# Understanding rank functioning in MySQL

Tags: mysql, dense-rank

I am trying to understand dense rank using variables in MySQL.

I created a table like:

```
create table scores (id int,score float);
```

Inserted values like this:

```
insert into scores values(1,3.50);
insert into scores values(2,3.65);
insert into scores values(3,4.00);
insert into scores values(4,3.85);
insert into scores values(5,4.00);
insert into scores values(6,3.65);
```

The query I wrote to rank the table using score like this:

```
set @rank=0;
set@score='';
select score,
   (@rank := if(@score = score, 
                @rank, 
                if(@score := score,    
                   @rank+1, 
                   @rank                    
                  )
               )                  
   ) as rank
from scores  
order by score desc;
```

When I ran the query "without" order by score desc
the out put was something like this:

```
score   rank 
3.5     1
3.65    2
4       3
3.85    4
4       5
3.65    6
```

When I ran the query "with" order by score desc, I got the output and it is something like this:

```
score   rank
4       1
4       1
3.85    2
3.65    3
3.65    3
3.5     4
```

What happens internally when using the snippet below?

```
select score,
   (@rank := if(@score = score, 
                @rank, 
                if(@score := score,    
                   @rank+1, 
                   @rank                    
                  )
               )                  
   ) as rank
from scores
```

Comment: Which part don't you understand exactly? Is there something that is unexpected to you?

Comment: @JanZeiseweis how internally the comparison is happening and the ran is updated ? this is where i am not clear.thanks in advance for your inputs

Answer (score 0):

Your ranking algorithm is basically just comparing the score of each row with the score of the previous row or '' (for the first row).
If the score is the same, it returns the same rank, if the score changed, it increases the rank by one.

**EDIT**

Btw, it does this after ordering the result set.

Comment: how internally the comparison is happening and the rank is updated ? this is where i am not clear.thanks in advance for your inputs

Comment: Is the answer not clear? The most important thing here is, that the score of each row is compared to the row before (above).
`if(@score = score, ` 
@score is the value of the score of the previous row, while 
`score` is the score value of the current row.
If they differ, the `@score` value is overwritten by `score` and `@rank` is increased by 1 (`@rank+1`).